# pyspark flat csv to nested json in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

```
Input CSV Data
userid,      Code,      Status
1234,        1 ,        final
1287,       2,        notfinal
```

```py
#Applied Pyspark Script    
#Create Spark Session
    spark =  SparkSession.builder.master("yarn").appName().enableHiveSupport().config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate()
    #read csv data into dataframe
    df =  spark.read.load("Book3.csv",format="csv", sep=",", inferSchema="true", header="true")
    #define schema for json df
    newschema = StructType([StructField("userid", StringType()),StructField("report", 
    StringType(),metadata={"maxlength":6000})])

    jsondf = df.rdd.map(lambda row: (row[0], ({"Code":row[1],"status" : row[2]})))\
    .map(lambda row: (row[0], json.dumps(row[1])))\
    .toDF(newschema) 
   
    jsondf.write.format("mongo").mode("append")\
    .option("uri","mongodb://gcp.mongodb.net/").option("database","dbname").option("collection", 
    "testcollection").save()
```

Resulant Mongo Data

```json
{
    "userid" : "1234",
    "report" : "{\"Code\": \"1\", \"status\": \"final\"}"
}
{
    "userid" : "1287",
    "report" : "{\"Code\": \"2\", \"status\": \"notfinal\"}"
}
```

In mongo i get a complete json encoded string in "report" which is not a surprise given i have taken report field as Stringtype().
This effectively makes any nested field based search in mongo impossible and whole code is useless then.
How can i make it a proper nested json so that mongo can search on nested fields as well ?
when i try to change field to proper structred json using below code

```py
>>> new_df = sql_context.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda r: r.json))
>>> new_df.printSchema()
```

i get error that "raise AttributeError(item) AttributeError: json"
**Please help with soem code tips...**
i am ok to use groupby as well but struggling what to put in aggregate functions and i need dataframe in result to write to mongo.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to properly define schema in pyspark "df_schema" and then map your base df into a new df "df_mongo" making sure that df.rdd.map should follow the pattern defined in df_schema .

```
df =  spark.read.load("sourcelocation",format="csv", sep="|", inferSchema="true", header="true")
df_schema = StructType([StructField("field1", StringType(),True),StructField("field2", StringType(),True)])            
df_mongo = df.rdd.map(lambda row: ([row[15],row[12]])).toDF(df_schema)
df_mongo.write.format("mongo").mode("append").option("uri",mongodb_uri). \ 
option("database",dbname).option("collection", collection_name).save()
```